# Similar triangles ratio of diagonal

Tags: geometry

This is an urgent homework help. I am trying this question since last two days but could not even get a hint.

$ABC$ is an triangle where D is mid point of side $BC$. $AD$ is bisected at E. $BE$ extended cuts cuts AC at X. Find $BE:EX$ = $3:1$.

I could not find any similar triangles. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Draw a line from $D$ to $BEX$, parallel to $AXC$

Comment: Thanks.What i tried was drawing a line from D to AXC parallel to BEX, which gave absurd result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B'$ be a mirror image of $B$ with respect to $A$. Then $EC||AD$ and so $BX$ bisects also $B'C$, say at point $Y$. So $X$ is gravity center for $B'BC$ and so $XY:BX = 1:2$. Since $E$ bisect also $BY$ it is easy to get conclusion.